# Proper way to add code to logout view in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I wrapped the `django.contrib.auth.views.logout` with another function to add additional behaviour. This is my new logout_page:

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
def logout_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.utils import timezone
    user = request.user
    profile = user.get_profile()
    profile.last_logout = timezone.now()
    profile.save()
    logout(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and

urls.py

```
(r'^logout/$', 'main.views.logout_page', {'next_page': '/'})
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
logout() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next_page'
```

I'm not sure why is 'next_page' an unexpected argument when logout contains **kwargs and as far as I know, logout from django.contrib.auth should contain such argument. From the source:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

```
def logout(request, next_page=None,
           template_name='registration/logged_out.html',
           redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
           current_app=None, extra_context=None):
...
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the wrong `logout`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
```

should be

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
```

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't get an error. I guess I was using the correct import except in my view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should import logout from views, `from django.contrib.auth.views import logout`, instead of `from django.contrib.auth import logout`.

On side note, for such behavior you may want to use logout signal.  Refer [login logout signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals)

Comment: Great suggestion, but I think it would be complicated by the fact that I can't use request.user in signals without a middleware, right?

Comment: @RobertSmith The relevant user is passed as an argument to the signal receiver, so you wouldn't need to access `request.user`.

Comment: @RobertSmith no `sender` parameter is the class, `user` is instance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you and used this simple workaround:

views.py:

```
def my_logout(request):
    # Staff you want to do before logout
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/logout2/")
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^logout/$', 'views.my_logout'),
url(r'^logout2/$',
    django.contrib.auth.views.logout,
    {'template_name': 'logged_out.html'},  # Next page
    name='auth_logout'),
```

Answer (score 0):

This has become a problem with the Django V2. You could define your login and logout functions in views and call them in the urls. Or you can follow the example given in the Django Documentation

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view()),